# Why there is no index in navigation bar item?

Tags: flutter, indexing, bottomnavigationview

This is the code without error messages:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

 class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => BottomNavigation();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class BottomNavigation extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions= <Widget>[
    Text('Home'),
    Text('Message')
  ];

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
  TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex=index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image:
                AssetImage("assets/OptimizeYourFood/OptimizeYourFood2.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
              color: Colors.transparent)
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_dining),
            label: 'Reduce',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.recycle),
            label: 'Reuse and recycle',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
[Nothing comes out of bottom navigation bar items][1]
```

..................................................................................................................................................................................................This is the end. This is the end. This is the end. This is the end. This is the end.

[New Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEKhT.png)

[New Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON6jr.png)

Comment: what is the last line? please don't spam.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the index but not the UI. use `_widgetOptions`  on body. You can directly use `body:_widgetOptions[_selectedIndex ]` .

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => BottomNavigation();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class BottomNavigation extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[Text('Home'), Text('Message')];

  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    print("tapped  $index");
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search), onPressed: () {}),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _widgetOptions[_selectedIndex]
          // Container(
          //     decoration: BoxDecoration(
          //         image: DecorationImage(
          //           image:
          //               AssetImage("assets/OptimizeYourFood/OptimizeYourFood2.png"),
          //           fit: BoxFit.cover,
          //         ),
          //         color: Colors.transparent)),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_dining),
            label: 'Reduce',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            //  Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.recycle),
            label: 'Reuse and recycle',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to flutter, do you know what I need to add for a gridview under the bottom navigation bar? Each grid view item also leads to another page. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to customize the bottom panel? Then you can use GridView  on `bottomNavigationBar:` you may need to provide height. Or maybe you want gridView on Body. if you can show an image, I may be able to tell

Comment: Yes, I used GridView on BottomNavigationBar, but I think I used the GridView in a wrong place, coz the GridView appears on all bottom navigation bar items. I just want to add a specific GridView for each item. Please see the attached picture "New code" in my question.

Comment: can you add image of layout that you want to archive?

Comment: Ok! I attached the layout , the gridview is under both bottom navigation bar items. I want the gridview under only "Reduce", and I want to create another gridview under "Reuse and Recycle".

Comment: Btw, I can't update the new code. Everything is the same except for picture 1 that I included. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will use the items array index.

```
items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem( // <- index 0
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_dining),
            label: 'Reduce',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem( // <- index 1
            icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.recycle),
            label: 'Reuse and recycle',
          ),
          ...
        ],
```

Comment: Hello, I set int _selectedIndex = 0; in the beginning. I tried your method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Actually I want to create the bottom navigation bar items which can lead to a list of items. If you have an idea which code I can use, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want to change body layout when you click BottomNavigationBar? If so, please follow @Yeasin Sheikh answer.